# How to push object in empty array

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

My code looks like this :

```
  router.put('/stories/:story', function(req,res,next){
  Story.findById(req.story._id, function(err, story) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        story.scenarios.push(req.body); 
        story.save(function(err,story) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json(story);
        })

    });
});
```

The req.body contains an object with an image and an audio.
I want to be able to update this array with new objects.
How do I push new objects to story.scenario (who is null in the beginning).

Now I get an error : 'cannot read property push of null'

Somebody who knows the solution?

Comment: Just initialize story.scenarios to an empty array before calling the push() method on it.

Comment: story.scenarios = []; story.scenarios.push(req.body);

Comment: Can you show your Story Schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `story.scenarios` is `null` at the very beginning so you need to initialize it as `[]` but you don't want to do it all the time since `story.scenarios` may already has data.

```
story.scenarios = story.scenarios || [];
story.scenarios.push(req.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

i am assuming `story` in the parameter is an `object` and it has `_id` present it. But still there  lies a problem in your code.

You cant just use `req.story` to access ths passed object. All such objects are accessed using `req.params`.

Change your code to this, and it should work.

```
Story.findById(req.params.story._id, function(err, story) {
...
});
```

Also, i am assuming, in your `Story Schema` you have declared `scenarios` as an array, and `req.body` matches the `type` you defined in the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize story.scenarios to be an empty array.
Then it calling the push() funciton.

ex

`story.scenarios = [];
story.scanarios.push(someData);`